# Custom post ID & display information related to this ID

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, advanced-custom-fields

I'm new to Wordpress and I want users to be able to retrieve a post by its ID.

For that I will be using a form in the homepage asking an ID and submitting the form will redirect user to the post's URL.

I see that as 2 steps:

1. use dynamic permalinks
2. display post information based on the ID (I am using CPT UI and ACF)

For step 1, I went to wp-admin/options-permalink and set it to "simple > http://.com/?p=123". Hopefully it's the good way, correct?

For step 2, how can I retrieve the ID from the URL and display the informations related to a particular post?

- should I edit a particular page like posts.php?
- how to edit this page? FTP or add-on?
- is there a way to do such thing from the UI directly?

Comment: Step 1 is unnecessary. If you open the URL `?p=123` you'll be redirected to that post. Step 2 is also unnecessary. Your theme should already display the content of the current post.

Comment: Based on this and your previous question I have no idea what you're trying to do, but you seem to be making a lot of assumptions about what you need to do it. You should start from the beginning and describe what you actually need.